# Python returning untrue values?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to Python, and I was working on a number guessing game in Python. However, when I set up the parameters:

```
import random
numberchosen = random.randint(0,100)
numberchosenstr = str(numberchosen)
print ("Let's play a number game")
numberguessed = input("Guess a number ")
print ("You guessed " + numberguessed)

if numberguessed > '100':
    print ("You guessed too high, choose a number below 100")

if numberguessed < '0':
    print ("You guessed too low, choose a number above 0")

if numberguessed != numberchosen:
    print ("wrong")
```

But, when I run the module, and choose the number 5 for instance, or any number that is within the correct range yet not the correct number, it always returns

```
Let's play a number game
Guess a number 5
You guessed 5
You guessed too high, choose a number below 100
wrong
```

So, my question is, why does Python return the >100 error, and what are some ways to fix it?

Comment: `'2' > '100'` --> `True`, don't compare strings.

Comment: You are comparing strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Apart from comparing strings to numbers your indentation of the print after the if statements is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're comparing strings, which is done lexicographically (i.e. alphabetically, one character at a time). But even if one were an int, strings are always greater than numbers. You need to take the quotes off your comparison number, and call `int()` on your `input`, like so:

```
numberguessed = int(input("Guess a number "))  # convert to int
print ("You guessed {}".format(numberguessed)) # changed this too, since it would error

if numberguessed > 100:  # removed quotes
    print ("You guessed too high, choose a number below 100")

if numberguessed < 0:    # removed quotes
    print ("You guessed too low, choose a number above 0")
```